# webscraper no longer retrieving data - can still access website via browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to webscraping and have been trying for fun to scrape a boxing website.
My code below was working on the first attempt, and when I tried to re-run it, it was no longer retrieving the link data any more.
I can still access the website from my browser, so not sure what the error is!
Appreciate any pointers.

```py
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

os.system('cls')

heavy = 'https://boxrec.com/en/ratings?r%5Brole%5D=box-pro&r%5Bsex%5D=M&r%5Bstatus%5D=a&r%5Bdivision%5D=Heavyweight&r%5Bcountry%5D=&r_go='

pages = set()

def get_links(page_url):
    print("running crawler...")
    global pages
    req = Request(heavy, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urlopen(req)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    for link in bs.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^(/en/box-pro/)')):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                new_page = link.attrs['href']
                print(new_page)
                pages.add(new_page)
                get_links(new_page)

get_links('')

print("crawling done.")
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You should describe your problem in the simplest way possible. There are parts of the code in your question that are not relevant for the case. Are you referring to the `html.read()`?

Comment: You need to login to be able to access that data across multiple pages. They probably added this requirement recently.

Comment: thanks @BarrythePlatipus seems this was the case - I've added a log in however they still do keep blocking my requests so I'm going to try rotating proxies as a next step...